# Can i sort the NSDictionary on basis of key in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, sorting, key, nsdictionary

Can I sort the `NSDictionary` on basis of key?

Comment: Did the answer provide you the right information? Maybe you can mark it as answer so this question will be marked as solved.

Answer (score 116):

You can sort the keys and then create an `NSMutableArray` by iterating over them.

```
NSArray *sortedKeys = [[dict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];
NSMutableArray *sortedValues = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *key in sortedKeys)
    [sortedValues addObject: [dict objectForKey: key]];
```

Comment: So is this a correct answer or not? got lots of votes, but no accept?

Comment: This is the correct answer. Sadly, the easier method (in iOS 7) of `[dictionary keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]` doesn't work. For some reason, it gives me results that are almost random in order. I'm wondering if `keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:` does something where it inserts into the array based on the last value of the array, which is kind of useless.

Comment: @mikeho: The method you mention is way older. But read it aloud: **keys *sorted by value***. It returns the keys of the dictionary when sorting the **value objects** using a selector. It does **not** return the keys sorted by that selector, which is what the code above does.

Comment: @MaxSeelemann: You're right! I misunderstood that. My interpretation of the name was the value of the key, not the value of the actual value associated with the key in the dictionary.

Comment: @mikeho: I can see where you're coming from. However that would be a very inconsistent naming according to Apple's framework standards. Although I realize that method should have rather been called `keysSortedByObjectUsingSelector:`

Comment: @MaxSeelemann: Yeah, I think it's more that it seems like a simple API to return the keys sorted is missing, so that threw me in for a loop. `NSDictionary` should have an API called `keysSortedUsingSelector:` to make things cleaner.

Comment: The answer should begin by "You can't sort a NSDictionary but..."

Answer (score 7):

It is much simpler to use `objectsForKeys:notFoundMarker:` for that

```
NSDictionary *yourDictionary;
NSArray *sortedKeys = [yourDictionary.allKeys sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES]]];
// As we using same keys from dictionary, we can put any non-nil value for the notFoundMarker, because it will never used
NSArray *sortedValues = [yourDictionary objectsForKeys:sortedKeys notFoundMarker:@""];
```