# Sort Dictionary by keys

Tags: swift, sorting, dictionary

I want to sort a dictionary in Swift. I have a dictionary like:

```
"A" => Array[]
"Z" => Array[]
"D" => Array[]
```

etc. I want it to be like

```
"A" => Array[]
"D" => Array[]
"Z" => Array[]
```

etc.

I have tried many solutions on SO but no one worked for me. I am using XCode6 Beta 5 and on it some are giving compiler error and some solutions are giving exceptions. So anyone who can post the working copy of dictionary sorting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can i sort the NSDictionary on basis of key in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583020/can-i-sort-the-nsdictionary-on-basis-of-key-in-objective-c)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59562/discussion-between-aleem-ahmad-and-dasblinkenlight).

Answer (score 203, accepted):

```
let dictionary = [
    "A" : [1, 2],
    "Z" : [3, 4],
    "D" : [5, 6]
]

let sortedKeys = Array(dictionary.keys).sorted(<) // ["A", "D", "Z"]
```

**EDIT:**

The sorted array from the above code contains keys only, while values have to be retrieved from the original dictionary. However, `'Dictionary'` is also a `'CollectionType'` of (key, value) pairs and we can use the global `'sorted'` function to get a sorted array containg both keys and values, like this:

```
let sortedKeysAndValues = sorted(dictionary) { $0.0 < $1.0 }
print(sortedKeysAndValues) // [(A, [1, 2]), (D, [5, 6]), (Z, [3, 4])]
```

**EDIT2:** The monthly changing Swift syntax currently prefers

```
let sortedKeys = Array(dictionary.keys).sort(<) // ["A", "D", "Z"]
```

The global `sorted` is deprecated.

Comment: Swift 3  = Array(dictionary.keys).sorted(by: <)

Comment: As of Swift 4, you can write `let sortedKeys = dictionary.keys.sorted()`

Comment: Since many things get duped here, worth mentioning that there is now OrderedDictionary in swift-collections. https://github.com/apple/swift-collections/blob/main/Documentation/OrderedDictionary.md

Answer (score 141):

To be clear, you cannot sort Dictionaries. But you can out put an array, which is sortable.

### Swift 2.0

Updated version of Ivica M's answer:

```
let wordDict = [
     "A" : [1, 2],
     "Z" : [3, 4],
     "D" : [5, 6]
]

let sortedDict = wordDict.sort { $0.0 < $1.0 }
print("\(sortedDict)") //
```

### Swift 3

```
wordDict.sorted(by: { $0.0 < $1.0 })
```

Comment: this actually returns an array of [(String, [Int])] not a Dictionary

Comment: realized Dictionaries are unsorted, so it doesnt make much sense to recreate the data type anyway. I ended up just saving an array of sorted keys.

Comment: I get `Binary operator > can not be compared to two `Any` operands. Downcasting doesn't work either

Answer (score 39):

In **Swift 5**, in order to sort Dictionary by KEYS

```
let sortedYourArray = YOURDICTIONARY.sorted( by: { $0.0 < $1.0 })
```

In order to sort Dictionary by VALUES

```
let sortedYourArray = YOURDICTIONARY.sorted( by: { $0.1 < $1.1 })
```

Comment: Note that this return a sorted array of dictionary elements. You can loop on it like it was a dictionary `for (key, value) in sortedDictArray { }`

Answer (score 36):

If you want to iterate over both the keys and the values in a key sorted order, this form is quite succinct

```
let d = [
    "A" : [1, 2],
    "Z" : [3, 4],
    "D" : [5, 6]
]
```

**Swift 1,2:**

```
for (k,v) in Array(d).sorted({$0.0 < $1.0}) {
    print("\(k):\(v)")
}
```

**Swift 3+:**

```
for (k,v) in Array(d).sorted(by: {$0.0 < $1.0}) {
    print("\(k):\(v)")
}
```

Comment: sorted is Custom method or What ?

it is showing error while implementing

Comment: @rikkyG Swift 1: `sort` and `sorted`. Swift 2: `sort` has become `sortInPlace` and `sorted` has become `sort`.

Answer (score 30):

I tried all of the above, in a nutshell all you need is

```
let sorted = dictionary.sorted { $0.key < $1.key }
let keysArraySorted = Array(sorted.map({ $0.key }))
let valuesArraySorted = Array(sorted.map({ $0.value }))
```

Answer (score 16):

In swift 4 you can write it smarter:

```
let d = [ 1 : "hello", 2 : "bye", -1 : "foo" ]
d = [Int : String](uniqueKeysWithValues: d.sorted{ $0.key < $1.key })
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort but first of all, the "let" doesn't make the code build, so first it needs to be "var".
Then after compile succeed this code doesn't work it doesn't sort the dictionary I get the same result before and after running this code.
Maybe I am missing something but please elaborate more or change the code.
=======
var d = [ 1 : "hello", 2 : "bye", -1 : "foo" ]
print(d) ->>> prints [2: "bye", -1: "foo", 1: "hello"]
d = [Int : String](uniqueKeysWithValues: d.sorted{ $0.key < $1.key })
print(d) ->>> prints [2: "bye", -1: "foo", 1: "hello"]

Comment: It is not possible as when you convert it back to dictionary it will change to the unordered collection as dictionaries in swift are unordered collection
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary

Answer (score 12):

**Swift 4 & 5**

For string keys sorting:

```
dictionary.keys.sorted(by: {$0.localizedStandardCompare($1) == .orderedAscending})
```

Example:

```
var dict : [String : Any] = ["10" : Any, "2" : Any, "20" : Any, "1" : Any]

dictionary.keys.sorted()
```

> `["1" : Any, "10" : Any, "2" : Any, "20" : Any]`

```
dictionary.keys.sorted(by: {$0.localizedStandardCompare($1) == .orderedAscending})
```

> `["1" : Any, "2" : Any, "10" : Any, "20" : Any]`

Answer (score 7):

For Swift 4 the following has worked for me:

```
let dicNumArray = ["q":[1,2,3,4,5],"a":[2,3,4,5,5],"s":[123,123,132,43,4],"t":[00,88,66,542,321]]

let sortedDic = dicNumArray.sorted { (aDic, bDic) -> Bool in
    return aDic.key < bDic.key
}
```

Comment: This doesn't return a Dictionary, this will return an array of tuples

Comment: @DanielArantesLoverde Dictionaries are unsortable by definition. An array of tuples is the best you can do.

Answer (score 7):

This is an elegant alternative to sorting the dictionary itself:

**As of Swift 4 & 5**

```
let sortedKeys = myDict.keys.sorted()

for key in sortedKeys {
   // Ordered iteration over the dictionary
   let val = myDict[key]
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 5**

Input your dictionary that you want to sort alphabetically by keys.

```
// Sort inputted dictionary with keys alphabetically.
func sortWithKeys(_ dict: [String: Any]) -> [String: Any] {
    let sorted = dict.sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key })
    var newDict: [String: Any] = [:]
    for sortedDict in sorted {
        newDict[sortedDict.key] = sortedDict.value
    }
    return newDict
}
```

**dict.sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key })** by it self returns a *tuple* (value, value) instead of a *dictionary* [value: value]. Thus, the for loop parses the tuple to return as a dictionary. That way, you put in a dictionary & get a dictionary back.

Comment: Dictionary could not be sorted, because it contain hashable mappings

Comment: for me not. try: 
var dict = ["Alise": [1,3,2], "Jane": [2,5], "Dany": [1]]
let sorted = sortWithKeys(dict)
it returns ["Dany": [1], "Alise": [1, 3, 2], "Jane": [2, 5]], because Dictionary has nothing with sorting
But sortedBy returns "[(key: "Alise", value: [1, 3, 2]), (key: "Dany", value: [1]), (key: "Jane", value: [2, 5])]\n"

Comment: When you create a new dictionary what is the guarantee that it will be sorted?

Comment: When creating a new dictionary you are simply setting keys and values so the order is not going to be respected.

Answer (score 3):

"sorted" in iOS 9 & xcode 7.3, swift 2.2 is impossible, change "sorted" to "sort", like this:

```
let dictionary = ["main course": 10.99, "dessert": 2.99, "salad": 5.99]
let sortedKeysAndValues = Array(dictionary).sort({ $0.0 < $1.0 })
print(sortedKeysAndValues)

//sortedKeysAndValues = ["desert": 2.99, "main course": 10.99, "salad": 5.99]
```

Comment: The result of sortedKeysAndValues is not a dictionary, it's an Array!

Comment: The result is an `Array` of `Tuples`, not a `Dictionary`

Answer (score 2):

For Swift 3, the following sort returnes sorted dictionary by keys:

```
let unsortedDictionary = ["4": "four", "2": "two", "1": "one", "3": "three"]

let sortedDictionary = unsortedDictionary.sorted(by: { $0.0.key < $0.1.key })

print(sortedDictionary)
// ["1": "one", "2": "two", "3": "three", "4": "four"]
```

Comment: This wont return a dictionary, this will return an array of Tuples

Comment: Don't you even read the question before putting your answer. You are wasting time of many people here. This question is specifically about sorting a dictionary and getting a sorted dictionary not array. I don't know why everyone is putting in wrong answers.

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 3 the following has worked for me and the Swift 2 syntax has not worked:

```
// menu is a dictionary in this example

var menu = ["main course": 10.99, "dessert": 2.99, "salad": 5.99]

let sortedDict = menu.sorted(by: <)

// without "by:" it does not work in Swift 3
```

Comment: This answer is pretty incomplete.  What is `sortedDict`?  What is `menu`?  This code does not appear to be valid, either.

Comment: Something more serious now: *a dictionary has no order*. What you get with your code is an array of tuples, not a sorted dictionary - as already said in some answers and comments.

Comment: "This answer is pretty incomplete. What is sortedDict? What is menu? This code does not appear to be valid, either. – cale_b" The answer was edited, the only thing missing was a declaration for a dictionaty - menu. I thought it was clear, this is only about a syntax change in Swift 3 as indicated. The code does work in Swift 3.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 is sorted(by:<)

```
let dictionary = [
    "A" : [1, 2],
    "Z" : [3, 4],
    "D" : [5, 6]
]

let sortedKeys = Array(dictionary.keys).sorted(by:<) // ["A", "D", "Z"]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift Sort Dictionary by keys**

Since `Dictionary`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70177026/4770877) is based on **hash** function it is not possible to use a sort function as we are used to(like Array). As an alternative you are able to implement a kind of **Java TreeMap/TreeSet**

Easiest way is to use `.sorted(by:)` function. It returns an sorted `Array` of `key/value` tupples which is easy to handle

Example:

```
struct Person {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
}

struct Section {
    let header: String
    let rows: [Int]
}

let persons = [
    Person(name: "A", age: 1),
    Person(name: "B", age: 1),
    Person(name: "C", age: 1),
    Person(name: "A", age: 2),
    Person(name: "B", age: 2),
    Person(name: "C", age: 2),
    Person(name: "A", age: 3),
    Person(name: "B", age: 3),
    Person(name: "C", age: 3),
]

//grouped
let personsGroupedByName: [String : [Person]] = Dictionary(grouping: persons, by: { $0.name })
/**
 personsGroupedByName
 [0] = {
   key = "B"
   value = 3 values {
     [0] = (name = "B", age = 1)
     [1] = (name = "B", age = 2)
     [2] = (name = "B", age = 3)
   }
 }
 [1] = {
   key = "A"
   value = 3 values {
     [0] = (name = "A", age = 1)
     [1] = (name = "A", age = 2)
     [2] = (name = "A", age = 3)
   }
 }
 [2] = {
   key = "C"
   value = 3 values {
     [0] = (name = "C", age = 1)
     [1] = (name = "C", age = 2)
     [2] = (name = "C", age = 3)
   }
 }
 */

//sort by key
let sortedPersonsGroupedByName: [Dictionary<String, [Person]>.Element] = personsGroupedByName.sorted(by: { $0.0 < $1.0 })
/**
 sortedPersonsGroupedByName
 [0] = {
     key = "A"
     value = 3 values {
       [0] = (name = "A", age = 1)
       [1] = (name = "A", age = 2)
       [2] = (name = "A", age = 3)
     }
   }
   [1] = {
     key = "B"
     value = 3 values {
       [0] = (name = "B", age = 1)
       [1] = (name = "B", age = 2)
       [2] = (name = "B", age = 3)
     }
   }
   [2] = {
     key = "C"
     value = 3 values {
       [0] = (name = "C", age = 1)
       [1] = (name = "C", age = 2)
       [2] = (name = "C", age = 3)
     }
   }
 */

//handle
let sections: [Section] = sortedPersonsGroupedByName.compactMap { (key: String, value: [Person]) -> Section in
    let rows = value.map { person -> Int in
        return person.age
    }
    return Section(header: key, rows: rows)
}
/**
 sections
 [0] = {
     header = "A"
     rows = 3 values {
       [0] = 1
       [1] = 2
       [2] = 3
     }
   }
   [1] = {
     header = "B"
     rows = 3 values {
       [0] = 1
       [1] = 2
       [2] = 3
     }
   }
   [2] = {
     header = "C"
     rows = 3 values {
       [0] = 1
       [1] = 2
       [2] = 3
     }
   }
 */
```

Answer (score -1):

my two cents, as all answers seem to miss we have a Dict and we do want a Dict:

```
var menu = ["main course": 10.99, "dessert": 2.99, "salad": 5.99]

let sortedMenu = menu.sorted(by: <) // is an ARRAY
print(type(of: sortedMenu))


let sortedDict = Dictionary( uniqueKeysWithValues: menu.sorted(by: <) )
print(type(of: sortedDict))
```

Above I sorted by value, by Key:

let sorted1 = menu.sorted { (kv1, kv2) in
return kv1.key < kv2.key
}
and/or apply conversion to Dict using constructor.