# dictionary value and keys in same order index Swift 1.2

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I try this

```
let dict: [String:String] = ["1":"one","2":"two","3":"three","4":"four"]
let keyArray = [String](dict.keys)
let valueArray = [String](dict.values)

println(dict)
println(keyArray)
println(valueArray)
```

i hope the result should be

```
//dict = ["1":"one","2":"two","3":"three","4":"four"]
//keyArray = ["1","2","3","4"]
//valueArray = ["one","two","three","four"]
```

but it's not it is

```
//dict = ["4": "four", "2": "two", "1": "one", "3":"three"]
//keyArray = ["4","2","1","3"]
//valueArray = ["four", "two", "one", "three"]
```

How do I get my hope result

Thank for any help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift: Sort Dictionary by keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25377177/swift-sort-dictionary-by-keys)

Answer (score 3):

From the Swift Language Guide

*A dictionary stores associations between keys of the same type and values of the same type in an collection* **with no defined ordering**.

If you want a kind of ordering, get the keys, order them and get the associated values.

There are custom classes `OrderedDictionary` on GitHub with a backing array for the keys to keep the order.