# Swift how to sort array dictionary by key values

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have a list of URL and its respective favourite counts obtained from firebase database appended into an array of dictionaries as such:

```
dictionaryArray = [[1: URL1], [2: URL2], [1: URL3]]
```

I understand that we can sort the array of dictionaries by using .sort but that removes dictionaries with similar keys like in this case.

how do I sort it such that I get an array of the url ordered by their keys to this:

```
urlArray = [URL2, URL1, URL3]
```

since URL2 has the higher key whereas URL1 and URL3 have similar keys

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort Dictionary by keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25377177/sort-dictionary-by-keys)

Comment: No no that doesn't explain what happens when there are duplicate keys. Ive tried that solution but it basically just removed the duplicates

Comment: Sorting a collection will *never* remove entries. Can you show what you exactly tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use higher-order functions sorted and flatMap nested together like so:

```
let sortedURLs = dictionaryArray
                    .sorted(by: { $0.keys.first! > $1.keys.first! })
                    .flatMap({ $0.values.first! })
```

Note: watch out of forced unwrapped optionals it is working here but could lead to an exception

Answer (score -1):

You can sort by using sort descriptors available like below.

```
var descriptor: NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
var sortedResults: NSArray = results.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([descriptor])
```