# How to show items in an array in a specific order?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

There are items that are based on an order in JSON that need to be returned in that specific order if their bool is true:

```
"items": {
    "item1": true,
    "item2": true,
    "item3": true,
    "item4": true,
    "item5": true,
    "item6": true
}
```

These items then need to show their corresponding images in order in a collectionview. Is there a way after adding these items to an array to get those itmes in the correct order?

This is the function I'm using now,it works but the order is different:

```
var appMenuJSON: NSDictionary?
var menuButtonsArray: [String?] = []

func getItems(){
    guard let items = appMenuJSON else {return}            
        for (key, value) in items {
            if let val = value as? Bool, val == true {
                menuButtonsArray.append(key as! String)
            }

}
```

Comment: Well there are some things that are not very clear in this question. First you say you have a JSON object but then in the code example it seems that this object is actually a NSDictionary?

Comment: the json file is used as a guide for what should be showed in UI. If it's value is true, it's supposed to show.

Comment: If your problem has nothing to do with the data being in JSON format, then leave it out of the question. It will clarify the question.

Answer (score 3):

Well once you decoded your JSON into a NSDictionary you have no way of getting the items back in the same order as they were in the JSON string.

So either sort the entries again using `Array(items).sort` (see [Sort Dictionary by keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25377177/sort-dictionary-by-keys)) or do a custom parsing of your JSON array to get the original ordering.