# Sorting through Dictionaries of array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, dictionary, multidimensional-array

Thanks for taking the time to look at the question.

I am trying to sort a Dictionary of Arrays in descending order, please see the data model below. I cannot use any of the sort methods on this array because the dictionary is nested inside another array.

```
var data = [[22 : [24 : 2, 35 : 3]], [21 : [24 : 21, 72 : 26 ]], [23 : [43 : 24, 53 : 12]]]
```

The sort methods don't recognize the dictionary as they are nested. Any thoughts?

```
var sortedKeysAndValues = Array(data.keys).sorted(<)
```

This throws an error: Value of type '[[Int : [Int: Int]]]' has no member 'keys'

```
data.sorted(by: { $0.0 < $1.0 })
```

This throws an error: Unable to infer closure type in the current context

Data  modal

```
[22 : [24 : 2, 35 : 3]]
```

The Key is 22. Which holds the value of another Dictionary Arrays [Int: Int, Int: Int]

Ideally want the results to be sorted by the key i.e 24, 23, and 22.

Much appreciate the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort Dictionary by keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25377177/sort-dictionary-by-keys)

Comment: No. If you look closer at my data model you will see that the dictionary is nested inside of another array.

Comment: how many keys can each dictionary element could have, and what's the logic then?

Comment: There is only one key for each dictionary element.  Let me add more info on that to the question.

Comment: Added more info let me know if that helps

Comment: You didn't answer my question... Could a dictionary, which is an element of the array, have multiple keys, or none? And if so, what's the sorting logic?

Comment: The dictionary which is an element of the array has 1 Int key and the sorting logic is just descending based on the Int key... The only issue I have is, the dictionary is nested inside of an another array so I cannot use any of the sort methods directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR

```
let asc = data.sorted(by: { $0.keys.first ?? Int.min < $1.keys.first ?? Int.min })
```

---

The general approach to sorting any array is to appropriately compare two arbitrary values within that array based on whatever property you want. Between the `first` and `second`, return `true` if `first` should be order *before* the `second`, based on some property of each.

In this case, each element is a dictionary of type: `[Int: [Int: Int]]`.

So, given two dictionaries, which property do use to compare?

Generally speaking, a dictionary could have zero to N keys, so you need to decide which key (or a combination of keys) you'd want to use in the sorting logic.

For your specific case, you could just use the first one (and assume that it always exists), by doing `dict.keys.first!` (forced unwrapped since it's an optional):

```
let asc  = data.sorted(by: { a, b in a.keys.first! < b.keys.first! })
let desc = data.sorted(by: { a, b in a.keys.first! > b.keys.first! })
```

But, using forced unwrapping isn't a good practice, so best to use nil-coalescing by deciding how you want to handle (hypothetical) empty dictionaries, e.g. with `Int.min` for empty dictionaries first:

```
let asc = data.sorted(by: { a, b in a.keys.first ?? Int.min < b.keys.first ?? Int.min })
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you. That worked. I didn't consider the "keys. first", when trying to solve this. Thanks for giving more information on the sorting.