# Filter the array in swift for given specific element from the array

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, filter

Following is the array I am receiving in response.  I have to show this data on `UITableView` where header title will be my `transactionDate` and items related to that date will go as number of rows in that section.

For below code, I have successfully pulled out unique dates from given list and I got 3 elements in unique date array.

Now I want another array which will have items associated to the date from unique date array.

So in result I should get 3 arrays for transactionDate value.
It should be like array1  with 2 value objects related to date `01/02/2021` array2 will be with 1 value related to date `27/01/2021` and array3 will be with 1 value object related to value to date `25/01/2021`

This data will go on increasing as transactions for given date will go on, so some dynamic implementation is needed.

My all data elements are in array `activityListArray` which contains all these elements.
Among which I have filtered out unique dates as below,

```
for i in activityListArray{
            date_array.append(i.transactionDate!)
        }
        let unique = Array(Set(date_array))
```

Now to get expected result what should I do next….?

Thanks in advance.

Response I am getting is below,

```
 {
            accountNumber = 0000078;
            amount = 0;
            buyingAmount = "277.42";
            buyingCurrency = EUR;
            currency = "";
            customerInstruction = "0201000009958346-000000218";
            payeeName = "Ash Roy";
            reasonCode = "";
            sellingAmount = "254.00";
            sellingCurrency = GBP;
            status = AWAITINGBANKAPPROVAL;
            subType = "Payment without Fx";
            transactionDate = "01/02/2021";
            type = "";
        },
                {
            amount = 0;
            buyingAmount = "436.39";
            buyingCurrency = GBP;
            currency = "";
            customerInstruction = "0201000009958346-000000210";
            reasonCode = "";
            sellingAmount = "788.00";
            sellingCurrency = CAD;
            status = PENDING;
            subType = "Payment without Fx";
            transactionDate = "27/01/2021";
            type = "";
        },
                {
            amount = 0;
            buyingAmount = "436.39";
            buyingCurrency = GBP;
            currency = "";
            customerInstruction = "0201000009958346-000000207";
            reasonCode = "";
            sellingAmount = "788.00";
            sellingCurrency = CAD;
            status = PENDING;
            subType = "Payment without Fx";
            transactionDate = "25/01/2021";
            type = "";
        },
                {
            amount = 0;
            buyingAmount = "436.39";
            buyingCurrency = GBP;
            currency = "";
            customerInstruction = "0201000009958346-000000206";
            reasonCode = "";
            sellingAmount = "788.00";
            sellingCurrency = CAD;
            status = PENDING;
            subType = "Payment without Fx";
            transactionDate = "01/02/2021";
            type = "";
        }
```

Comment: You can use `Dictionary(grouping:by)` to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to pull out unique dates, Swift standard library has already provided an API to Dictionary, where in you can group the collection of objects based on specific field using `init(grouping:by:)`

read all about it here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127163-init

```
let dict = Dictionary<String,[YourObject]>(grouping: activityListArray, by: {$0.transactionDate})
```

BTW `Dictionary<String,[YourObject]>` explicit type declaration is not needed, just realised it, so it can be as simple as

```
let dict = Dictionary(grouping: activityListArray, by: {$0.transactionDate})
```

This will return a Dictionary with unique transactionDate as keys and array of objects with that transactionDate as values.

Now you can simply return number of sections as `dict.keys.count` and number of rows in each section as `dict[Array(dict.keys)[indexPath.section]]?.count`

Comment: @sagar: Please check the answer posted and lemme know if you are still facing issue, if its working fine please consider accepting the answer

Comment: @ Sandeep Bhandari :- Thanks buddy, that helped me a lot and kudos to answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: @sagar: glad I could help :)

Comment: @ Sandeep Bhandari:- Just quick update help needed, can we sort the data using transactionDate in ascending or descending order....? Any tips for the same

Comment: You can, simply search sorting dictionary keys :) That should do the job, lemme check if I can find already answered question

Comment: `let sortedKeys = Array(dictionary.keys).sorted(<)` take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25377177/sort-dictionary-by-keys from now on use `sortedKeys.count` for number of section and use `dict[sortedKeys[indexPath.section]]?.count` for number of cells in section finally use `dict[sortedKeys[indexPath.section]][indexPath.row]` probably to return cell, none of these are compiled codes typed directly in comment so might have compilation error :)

Comment: @ Sandeep Bhandari :- thanks, I got the codes, will do necessary modifications and I am good to go. Thanks for help.

Comment: @sagar tell me here, you can convert this to a chat if you want, adding duplicate questions will not help anybody

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228940/discussion-between-sagar-and-sandeep-bhandari).