# How to sort key in a dictionary in swift?

Tags: swift

I am trying to build a generic function that arranges the keys of a dictionary in ascending order. The code below doesn’t perform the task correctly. How do I resolve it?

```
func sortKeysx<T: Comparable>(value: [T:T])->[T:T] {
        let sorted = value.sorted{ $0.key < $1.key }
        return Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: sorted)
    }
    
    
sortKeysx(value: [5.0:3, 4.0:2, 3.0:7, 2.0:1])

output: [3.0: 7.0, 4.0: 2.0, 5.0: 3.0, 2.0: 1.0]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort Dictionary by keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25377177/sort-dictionary-by-keys)

Comment: The gist of the answers given above: You can iterate over a `Dictionary` in key order, and you can use that iteration order to read the keys and values into order-preserving data structures like `Array`s or an `OrderedDictionary`. But `Dictionary`s aren't order-preserving, so don't use one if you care about the order.

Comment: Please provide an example, I don't quite understand

Comment: Can you go to the link in my first comment? They explain it pretty well there.

Comment: Don't expect a Dictionary preserve the key order. Use different data structure and logic to achieve your goal. Even if the compiler implementation does preserve key order, the specification of the data structure does not. So don't treat it as guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

The `Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: sorted)` call does not provide any guarantee to preserve the order of keys.

You may want to use an [`OrderedDictionary`](https://github.com/apple/swift-collections/blob/main/Documentation/OrderedDictionary.md) instead.