# Weird sorting when parsing JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on an App and I use my JSON RESTful API. Therefor I parse JSON like in the following example:

```
NSData * apiReturn;
NSError *myError = nil;
NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:apiReturn options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];
```

If I now pass the following JSON encoded String via the API to the App:

> {"da": {"name":"dienstlicher Anlass", "duty":true, "type":"dropdown", 
>   "values":{"gt":{"name":"Gesprächstermin", "recurring":true,
>   "values":{"fa":{"name":"Firma", "duty":true, "type":"text",
>   "multiline":false}, "ar":{"name":"Anrede", "duty":true, "single":true,
>   "type":"checkbox", "values":{"fr":{"name":"Frau"},
>   "hr":{"name":"Herr"}}}, "nm":{"name":"Gesprächspartner", "duty":true,
>   "type":"text", "multiline":false}, "bm":{"name":"Bemerkung",
>   "duty":false, "type":"text", "multiline":true}}}}
>   },"bm":{"name":"Bemerkung", "values":[],
>   "type":"text"},"bm2":{"name":"Bemerkung", "values":[], "type":"text"}}

(You can parse this a bit prettier here: http://json.parser.online.fr)

The NSDictionary should contain the following Keys: "da", "bm", "bm2" - Sorted this way, because this is the sorting of the JSON String!

But what Objective-C does, is this:

[image: wrong sorting]

Why does Objective-C sort the elements, and why so wrong?

I hope you can help! :)

Comment: A JSON "object" (dictionary) does not guarantee that entry order is maintained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An NSDictionary is not guaranteed to store the keys in any given order.

Comment: Do you know any alternative?

Comment: You can use this alternative : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583020/can-i-sort-the-nsdictionary-on-basis-of-key-in-objective-c

Comment: @ChristopherMäuer check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/376090/nsdictionary-with-ordered-keys

Comment: If I am not wrong, this will sort the elements by their name? This is not what I want!

Comment: @ChristopherMäuer I think that if you care about order, you should be using arrays

Comment: Maybe I should add a value "sorting" to it with an Integer, and the sort with the method @CRDave wrote?

Comment: Is it possible to parse JSON to an Array, because whatever I do, it will give me a NSDictionary!

Comment: @ChristopherMäuer It's giving you a dictionary because you're feeding it a dictionary. Each element at the `values` key in your JSON is an array, use that for reference.