# Dictionary keys sorted as they came in http response with Mantle

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, github-mantle

You parse a property as a NSDictionary object in a MTLModel object, and then, you get the keys with `allkeys` method.

```
@interface SomeModel : MTLModel<MTLJSONSerializing>

@property (copy, nonatomic, readonly) NSDictionary *dictionary;

@end
```

...

```
NSArray *keys = [dictionary allkeys];
```

The returned keys are not usually sorted the same way they came in the HTTP response body.

For instance, the http response is this:

```
{"someObject":{"key1": "valueOfKey1", "key2": "valueOfKey2", "key3": "valueOfKey3",}}
```

but then, the NSDictionary keys are returned like this:

```
{"key2", "key1", "key3"}
```

How can you get the keys sorted as they came?

I have personally tested this, but it doesn't work:

```
[[dict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can i sort the NSDictionary on basis of key in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583020/can-i-sort-the-nsdictionary-on-basis-of-key-in-objective-c)

Comment: The answer is you cant. You have to use sortedArrayUsingSelector or sortedArrayUsingComparator ans sort them according to NSComparisonResult.

NSArray *sortedArray = [[dict allKeys]  sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id  _Nonnull obj1, id  _Nonnull obj2) {
        NSString *key1 = obj1;
        NSString *key2 = obj2;
        return [key2 compare:key1] == NSOrderedDescending;
    }];